# AssertJ: what is the difference between containsOnly and containsExactlyInAnyOrder

Tags: list, unit-testing, junit, assert, assertj

[AbstractIterableAssert#containsOnly](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnly(ELEMENT...)) says:

> Verifies that the actual group contains only the given values and nothing else, in any order.

[AbstractIterableAssert#containsExactlyInAnyOrder](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT...)) says:

> Verifies that the actual group contains exactly the given values and nothing else, **in any order**.

The description looks almost the same, so **what is actual difference between *only* and *exactly***?

Answer (score 22):

The actual difference is matter only if the expected and actual collections/lists **contain duplicates**:

- `containsOnly` is always duplicates **in***sensitive*: it never fails if sets of expected/actual values are matched
- `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` is always duplicates ***sensitive***: it fails if the numbers of expected/actual elements are different

Although, they all fail if:

- at least one expected *unique* value is missing in the actual collection
- not every *unique* value from actual collection is asserted

See the example:

```java
private List<String> withDuplicates;
private List<String> noDuplicates;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    withDuplicates = asList("Entryway", "Underhalls", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls", "Entryway");
    noDuplicates = asList("Entryway", "Underhalls", "The Gauntlet");
}

@Test
public void exactMatches_SUCCESS() throws Exception {
    // successes because these 4 cases are exact matches (bored cases)
    assertThat(withDuplicates).containsOnly("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls", "Entryway", "Underhalls"); // 1
    assertThat(withDuplicates).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls", "Entryway", "Underhalls"); // 2

    assertThat(noDuplicates).containsOnly("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls"); // 3
    assertThat(noDuplicates).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls"); // 4
}

@Test
public void duplicatesAreIgnored_SUCCESS() throws Exception {
    // successes because actual withDuplicates contains only 3 UNIQUE values
    assertThat(withDuplicates).containsOnly("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls"); // 5

    // successes because actual noDuplicates contains ANY of 5 expected values
    assertThat(noDuplicates).containsOnly("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls", "Entryway", "Underhalls"); // 6
}

@Test
public void duplicatesCauseFailure_FAIL() throws Exception {
    SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softly -> {
        // fails because ["Underhalls", "Entryway"] are UNEXPECTED in actual withDuplicates collection
        softly.assertThat(withDuplicates).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls"); // 7

        // fails because ["Entryway", "Underhalls"] are MISSING in actual noDuplicates collection
        softly.assertThat(noDuplicates).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Entryway", "The Gauntlet", "Underhalls", "Entryway", "Underhalls"); // 8
    });
}
```

Comment: I was about to clarify that in `containsOnly` javadoc, one more reason to do it.

Comment: done https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/6983158e5ea2f6fe54c864fc0dd7ec9b672e4653/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/ObjectEnumerableAssert.java#L61

Comment: flawless explanation @radistao